Need Information on Vernitron Motor Model 15H4B-AA0-A2
I’m looking for a Vernitron Corporation motor, specifically model 15H4B-AA0-A2. If anyone has a datasheet, or any details about this motor, I would greatly appreciate your help.

I'm not sure if Vernitron Corporation still exist or have been taken over by a different company, but searching for 15H4B-AA0-A2 it appears that part number was intended for aerospace or military applications.
Buy 15H4B-AA0-A2 with NSN 6105-01-192-3049 by General Dynamics Global Imaging  lists the the 15H4B-AA0-A2 part number and has the following Characteristics Data of NSN 6105-01-192-3049, 6105011923049 table:



MRC
Criteria
Characteristic




AAJU
III OVERALL LENGTH
2.000 INCHES


AAJV
OVERALL WIDTH
1.437 INCHES


AAUH
SPLINE MINOR DIAMETER
0.1562 INCHES NOMINAL SINGLE END


ABWV
SHAFT DIAMETER
0.1875 INCHES NOMINAL SINGLE END


AKPS
DUTY CYCLE
CONTINUOUS


ANPZ
INCLOSURE FEATURE
TOTALLY INCLOSED


ANTN
SPECIFIC USE
F/TF-15A ACFT,FSCM 76301


AXCP
WINDING TYPE
INDUCTION-SINGLE VALUE CAPACITOR SPLIT PHASE


AXFH
SPLINE LENGTH
0.2700 INCHES NOMINAL SINGLE END


AXGY
MOUNTING METHOD
CLAMP RING


AXHR
MOUNTING FACILITY TYPE AND QUANTITY
1 CLAMP COLLAR


BFMF
COOLING METHOD
AMBIENT AIR


BKPH
TORQUE RATING AND TYPE
30.0 INCH-OUNCES RUNNING


BKPQ
INCLOSURE SPECIFICATION
COMMERCIAL


CNXS
POWER RATING
20.0000 WATTS OUTPUT


CWFX
ROTOR SPEED RATING IN RPM
12000.0 SINGLE FULL LOAD


CWGQ
CONNECTION TYPE AND VOLTAGE RATING IN VOLTS
115.000 LINE TO NEUTRAL SINGLE INPUT


FAAZ
PHASE
TWO INPUT



The above web page also gives the National Stock Number (NSN) 6105-01-192-3049 for the 15H4B-AA0-A2 part number.
NSN Code 6105-01-192-3049 of Motor Alternating C - 6105011923049 Component Sourcing contains other motor part numbers for the same NSN, so their might be other drop-in replacements for the 15H4B-AA0-A2 motor. I haven't attempted to the compare the specifications for the alternative part numbers, but perhaps they have datasheets available.
